# C++ - Loading Text Won't Repeat

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++, so please explain in a way I will be able to understand. Thanks!

Okay, here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//This function

void loadprog(int times){
        for(int x = 0; x <= times; x++){
            cout << "Loading information.\r";
            Sleep(500);
            cout << "Loading information..\r";
            Sleep(500);
            cout << "Loading information...\r";
            Sleep(500);
        }
}


int main(){
    string login_name;
    string login_auth;
    bool authcheck = true;
    while(authcheck == true){
        cout << "Account login: ";
        cin >> login_name;
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Account authentication: ";
        cin >> login_auth;

        if(login_name == "syd" && login_auth == "boyle"){
            authcheck = false;
            cout << "Success.\n";
            loadprog(6);
        }
        else{
            cout << "Failure.\n\n";
        }
    }
    Sleep(6000);
    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to achieve a line print out 'Loading information', with a new dot added every half a second, until it reaches three dots, when it will go back to one (but only if it passes the for() loop). Instead, I'm getting very strange behavior. Once it gets to three dots, it simply stays as three dots, not going back to one to start over. Why is this happening?! It's driving me nuts! Thanks again.

Comment: `loadprog(6);` should be `loadprog(1);` if you want just a single iteration of `.` `..` `...`

Comment: the dots that are put in the first iteration has to be cleared

Comment: What are you expecting to happen to those dots and where is the code to do whatever that is to them? You have no code to do anything to those dots, so nothing is ever done to them.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing last dots. You could solve it by changing output strings:

```
void loadprog(int times){
        for(int x = 0; x <= times; x++){
            cout << "Loading information.  \r"; //<- added 2 spaces here
            Sleep(500);
            cout << "Loading information.. \r"; //<- added 1 space here
            Sleep(500);
            cout << "Loading information...\r";
            Sleep(500);
        }
}
```

Also you should notice that you repeat this output not for "times" times but for "times + 1" times because you repeat it for x = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 == 7 times.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I had found a bug in C++, I was getting so frustrated.